# read() in c raspberry pi gsm-module

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, uart

I am working on a project where i can send sms with my raspberry pi thats connected to a sim300s module thrue a usb to serial connection. 
problem:
 sim300 doesnt detect the simcard , harware malfunction, i have ordered a new one. Until then i want to check if the connection works between the 2.

Now i want to send at command and receive OK(or something like that) Here is my code:
the value that is stored in string buf is TATATATAT.... etc.. etc..

**Can someone explain why i am not getting OK back? Am i doing something wrong?**

```
 #include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
 #include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
 #include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
 #include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
 #include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
 #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

/* 
  * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
  *
  * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
  */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

puts("start open_port");
open_port();
puts("open_port started ");
}

 int
 open_port(void)
 {
   char reply;//not shure if its gonna be used
   struct termios options;
   int n=0;
   int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
   char buf[50];
   int valueBytes;
   int x = 0;


   fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); //| O_NDELAY);
   if (fd == -1)
   {//could not open port
     fprintf(stderr, "open_port: Unable to open /dev/ - %s\n",
             strerror(errno));
   }

   printf("%d",fd);
    tcgetattr(fd, &options); //get current options for port
puts("test1"); 
    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);//set baud rate
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);//set baud rate
puts("\n2");
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD | CRTSCTS);//enable the receiver and set local mode
puts("\n3");
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;//disable parity generation and detection
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;//Use one stop bit per character
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;//use 8 bits  to send or receive characters

    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | /* Enable canonical input (else raw) */
    ECHO | /*Enable echoing of input characters */
    ECHOE | /*Echo erase character as BS-SP-BS*/
    ISIG); /*Enable SIGINTR, SIGSUSP, SIGDSUSP, and SIGQUIT signals*/

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);//TCSANOW change values immediately
puts("4");
n = write(fd, "AT\r", 4);  // n = write(fd, "AT+CMGF=1\r", 10);
  if (n < 0){
    puts("write() of 4 bytes failed!");}


if(read(fd, buf, 2) < 0){
 puts("it doesnt work"); }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    valueBytes=read(fd, buf,50);
printf("%d",valueBytes);
    if(valueBytes < 0){
    printf(strerror(errno));}
puts("6.3");

for(x; x<50;x++){
printf("%c",buf[x]);
}

   close(fd);
puts("7");
 return (fd); 
puts("8");
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect an OK back? The code above doesn't send a command to the module. (I'd recommand starting with `"AT\r"` which the module should respond to with `OK`

Comment: n = write(fd, "AT\r", 4); gives same result

Comment: I don't have the datasheet to hand, but the sim300 might be autobauding by default. You may have to send the `"AT\r"` command multiple times so the module can detect the correct baudrate. Once this occurs it will respond with `"OK"`. If you can, hook up the module to your PC and connect with hyperterminal. This should make it easier to enter some initial commands.